# Concatenate auto increment value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script with this HTML. I want to create a dynamic form that I can to add new inputs. This script works but I need to add in name on input a number to identify like width1, width2... and a hidden field that contains the total number of input that I create for passing to php. How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
   
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="width">');
        }
    });
```

```html
<form method="post">
 
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add other</button>
    <input type="text" name="width"><br><br>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="send" value="Generate">

</form>
```

Comment: do you really need a unique name? The nodes are already "unique" within the dom tree, and you can trivially figure out which is which based on which child of the parent/container `<div>` they are.

Comment: all input fields has the same name="width" when i add more of one using jquery the name attributte is the same "width" i need to add auto increment number for example width1,width2...for php can interpretate if i send the form with the same name in the input field php only catch the last one

Comment: then use `width[]`. the `[]` tells php to expect multiple values with the same name, and to create an array of them.

Comment: do you say for example <input type="text" name="width[]">? and i can use a foreach in php directly?

Comment: why don't you try it? put in a bunch of `width[]` fields, then `var_dump($_POST)` in php to see what you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the id attributes to be unique, and make the `name` field take multiple values as an array instead of just one value. See example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
   
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<input type="text" name="width[]" id="width'+x+'">');
        }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
 
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add other</button>
    <input type="text" name="width[]"><br><br>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="send" value="Generate">

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks friend this works perfect i only needed to concatenate the auto increment number to the name